# OpenGL glClearColor always make a black screen

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I'm trying to run my first opengl program in C++, which opens a window, sets a background color, and gives a title, from Terminal on Mac OS X.

The code compiles and links fine. When I run the program the window and title open fine but the background color is always black.

It is my understanding that the function `glClearColor` sets the background color. However, no matter what parameters I pass to the function, the background color of the window is always black.

If anyone can explain to me what errors I'm making, I would very much appreciate it. Thanks and below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

const GLint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Learn OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);

    if(nullptr == window)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << '\n';
        glfwTerminate();

        return -1;
    }

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err=glewInit();

    if(err != glewInit())
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << '\n';

        return -1;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.9f, 0.5f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`glClearColor`, like all OpenGL functions, works on the current OpenGL context.

You're not setting your window's context as current for your calling thread, so your call to `glClearColor` does nothing here. Add:

```
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
```

before your loop.

From [glfwMakeContextCurrent](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__context.html#ga1c04dc242268f827290fe40aa1c91157) docs:

> This function makes the OpenGL or OpenGL ES context of the specified window current on the calling thread. A context can only be made current on a single thread at a time and each thread can have only a single current context at a time.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you crazy enough to use pure **WIN32** programming:

If your PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR has the flag:

**PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER**

Then all draw calls target the back buffer.

You need to use the windows GDI32 call **"SwapBuffers( HDC )"** to show the results of your OpenGL calls.

```
wlgMakeCurrent()
glClearColor( R, G, B, 1.0 ); //: <--Make sure alpha isn't transparent.
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT )
SwapBuffers( your_window_HDC ); //: from GDI32.dll
```

To get access to SwapBuffers I use **LoadLibrary** and **GetProcAddress** and
put the function pointer in my Win32 functions library.

Also notworthy:

Call SwapBuffers on the **same thread** as your OpenGL calls.

One more thing. I used multiple threads. So this might be helpful to know:

- 1. My window was created in thread "B"
- 2. My Context was created in thread "A" using HDC from thread "B"
- 3. My openGL draw calls are in thread "A".

I mention this because before I found out about **SwapBuffers** I thought the problem was because of my multi threading. OpenGL wasn't giving me any errors though, so I had to guess around and experiment and read.